# How to search sourceforge.net for Java projects that are built in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, sourceforge

Sourceforge.net has a [filter for Java projects](http://sourceforge.net/directory/language%3ajava/), but I'm looking for a way to narrow them down to ones that are meant to be built in Eclipse.

**Edit** I'm using Eclipse Metrics and Omondo plug-ins to analyze open-source Java projects. I'm looking for a quick way to find Eclipse open-source projects that can build quickly in Eclipse, so I can use these tools on them for analysis.

Comment: Which Java projects at SourceForge *cannot* be built using Eclipse?

Comment: Some require Ant or Maven, for example.

Comment: Eclipse has Ant built-in AFAIR.

Comment: And typing "Maven eclpise" into my favorite search engine and hitting enter returns "Showing results for Maven *eclipse*" ..and some likely candidates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume that a project that is "meant to be built in Eclipse" is one that has an Eclipse `.project` file and other stuff checked into the source repository.

First, checking in Eclipse-specific stuff can a bad idea because it is easy to include stuff (e.g. build pathnames, preferences) that are specific to the developer.  You then get problems if there are multiple committers ...

Second, this should unnecessary.  Most of the stuff in the .project file can be generated when you import the project.  If that's not possible, then the project should provide instructions for setting up the buildpath etcetera.  (Note that if the project uses Maven, this is all taken care of for you.)

Third, any project worth its salt will include build scripts of some kind that allow you to rebuild without using *any* IDE.

Finally, any project that only supports building using Eclipse is excluding the significant subset of developers who use other Java IDEs.

---

Note that neither Maven or Ant builds require Eclipse to work.  Both of these build tools can run from the command line, or from other Java IDEs.

---

OK.  I understand your requirements now.  You don't actually care what the project is ... or that it is sound / worthwhile project.  You just need it for testing your plugin.  (I won't comment on the "validity" of doing this.  It depends on what you hope to achieve.)

I suggest that you install the m2eclipse plugin and look for projects with a "pom.xml" file.  The projects don't need to be eclipse specific.  The m2eclipse plugin automatically creates the ".project", ".classpath" and so on based on the "pom.xml" file.  There's no need to exclude any particular version control system, because the m2eclipse plugin can import Maven projects that you checked out from the command line.

Comment: The metrics plugins and UML reverse engineering tools I'm using are eclipse based and require java byte code. I want to try them out on some sourceforge projects but don't want to lose time with those that don't build easily in eclipse.

Comment: The `.project` keyword won't work in Sourceforge's search. Using "Eclipse" keyword doesn't either, since it only returns Eclipse plug-ins (it seems). `".project"` *does* work in Google with `site:sourceforge.net`, and that gets me someplace.

Comment: OK, here's what I am using in Google, which includes some of the hints from your text: `maven ".project" ".cvsignore" site:sourceforge.net` -- I added the .cvsignore to find projects that can be easily imported into vanilla Eclipse using CVS (hopefully to avoid projects that are SVN only, since I don't want to depend on subclipse, etc.).

Comment: Thanks for the edits about m2eclipse - I accepted the answer.

Comment: Also, re: "(I won't comment on the "validity" of doing this. It depends on what you hope to achieve.)" -- It's academic :) I'm teaching students how to re-engineer UML from source code (via Omondo), how some software metrics are not as useful as you might think (via Eclipse Metrics), etc. Eclipse is a very easy environment to teach with, and every student has to use a different open source project so I don't have to check for plagiarism in the assignments.

Comment: *"... so I don't have to check for plagiarism in the assignments."* - Ughh!  So how are you going to mark the assignments?  How will you know that the answers are correct?  It sounds like you will have to do the analysis for all N projects yourself to check that the submissions are correct.  Surely it would be less work to just check for plagiarism ...

Comment: Of course, I do have to check for plagiarism, but it's highly unlikely when nobody else has done the study in the context of my course history. This is not a programming assignment. Also, it's the first of three assignments using the same project for appreciating/critiquing design aspects of software. I can explain it to you offline if you're really interested.

Comment: What I *meant* was that I think it would be easier to set one "project" and check for students plagiarising each other than it would be to set N different projects and incur the extra marking overheads.  But obviously it is your call ...

Comment: At the end of the semester the students present to everyone their experiences (which are all different, as no two projects are the same). This is a great way for everyone to learn, although marking is more subjective as a result. I *wish* marking were more objective in design-related coursework; even if everyone had the same project, there's no single "correct" answer in design (except maybe for trivial problems).

Comment: Now *that* is a really good reason to make the projects different.